# iptables, forwarding between interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing

I'm trying to setup a router using iptables.

But, after a lot of examples I've tried, I can't get anything to work.

My idea is to setup a box in between my Cisco and the main switch for firewall, bandwidth graphs, filtering, etc.

I am using an old laptop as a test unit for now.

- Interface `eth0` is static with an ip of 192.168.10.5/255.255.255.0
  and gw 192.168.10.1. This works as a valid Internet connection.
- Interface `eth1` is static with an ip of 192.168.10.6/255.255.255.0.

I have forwarding enabled via `sysctl.conf` and double checked the value inside ip_forward.

When I connect a test Windows laptop via cable to eth1, I get no DHCP
(dhcp is handled by the Cisco on 192.168.10.1). This is normal I suspect
since I need several iptable rules, but the question is which? I have tried
so many variations but none seem to work, can anyone help me please?

Summary:

```
cisco: 192.168.10.1
eth0 : 192.168.10.5
eth1 : 192.168.10.6
```

CISCO<->[eth0]box[eth1]<->devices(eg. Windows laptop)